# Before save action and validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My application has a logic:
Parent model before save generates child model elements.

I'd like to validate before save parent element that it has at least one child element.

I tried use validates_presence_of, but it called before 'before_save' so parent doesn't have child elements.

Could you please tell me where I should generate child elements and where validate presence or absence of child elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I misunderstood your problem, but you want to check if Parent model has at least 1 child before the Parent model triggers 'before_save' callback (which will do whatever it wants), right?

If yes, you can use 'before_validation' callback.  'before_validation' is called before 'before_save'.  So you can do something like:

```
before_validation { self.errors.add(:base, 'error here or something') if self.children.count < 1 }
```

Note that rails will not even try to save the resource if resource's 'errors' array is not empty (so before_save callback will not be called). doing 'self.errors.add' in the 'before_save' callback will not stop the resource from being saved.  If you want to stop the resource from being saved from the 'before_save' callback you can do:

```
before_save do 
  self.errors.add(:base, 'error here or something')
  false
end
```

Hope that helped. :)

Cheers!

Comment: thanks for answer. Nope, opposite - I generate child elements in `before_save` callback when parsing file data and I want check after I parse file, that parent have at least one element, else it means that the file format was incorrect.

Comment: In that case you just do the parsing and checking inside the before_save and just make sure you do errors.add and return false if the format is incorrect. :)  Glad I can be help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
class Hero < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :weapons

  before_save :check_equipment

  private
    def check_equipment
      errors.add(:weapons, "are not equipped") if weapons.size < 1 
    end
end

class Weapon < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hero
end
```

You can create weapon as independent object and then associate the weapon with heros, or you can also create weapon with the hero just use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method. The solution depends on you application architecture.

Comment: i'm not sure but `validates :weapons, presence: true` can work too

Comment: Where should I generate weapons?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. In my parent model `before_save :parse_file`, so, should I add second method to before save or move :parse_file to another place?

Comment: Try before _save :parse_file, :check_weapon

Comment: should I check in some place errors that I add or it will check automatically and generate notice?

Comment: I tried it but while I did not save child elements I get that child.count = 0. So, don't know how to approach this task